# Gmaps not getting displayed on emulator.

Tags: java, android, permissions, google-play-services, android-maps

## while developing android app with gmaps i got error like this and my code as follows

the app wont run unless you update google play services shows in emulator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ant"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission         android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAGcKOhosFI0OO_QbvaNSzDdRqj3S2tEvE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ant.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>




</manifest>
```

and my main activity is like this

mainactivity.java

```
package com.ant;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;





public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
// Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Comment: add xml name space to your relative layout:    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0):

Please remove app from your device and reinstall.